# Population pyramid using barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot a population pyramid using code based upon barplot that I've [found here](http://www.jps29.fr/spip.php?article51), however I'm having problems setting the values for the left axis (no numbers after the decimal point) and the y-axis is missing.

[image]

See [original picture here](http://tinypic.com/r/zssj8x/5)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here's the data:

```
pop.F<-c(0.537717667361149, 0.514712848921534, 0.537717073399189, 0.557084545268768, 
0.567834397004932, 0.582139298825445, 0.565957418909337, 0.586423112026536, 
0.587410059280687, 0.602473037729535, 0.596951974181498, 0.595324094329212, 
0.594376818092194, 0.582963584503263, 0.591416648023927, 0.604261422088911, 
0.567883789565167, 0.594503659844329, 0.469344234910119, 0.501841457211355, 
0.491217852325057, 0.490726173434756, 0.464565125135902, 0.493308069660213, 
0.522676581503902, 0.512085654241981, 0.536695926786982, 0.57145121599885, 
0.597089551756897, 0.60072309822413, 0.576708534734466, 0.577187793080901, 
0.576849827784843, 0.601365414017059, 0.623847536527997, 0.670070277869142, 
0.71956647333944, 0.722278976001524, 0.75496827807844, 0.78962490535034, 
0.740987864729483, 0.747682754143878, 0.78430364088942, 0.777897375927852, 
0.763466595545233, 0.801284460136153, 0.804158302613309, 0.782873919284743, 
0.776571715204978, 0.7673806142982, 0.769488669611802, 0.745459310984175, 
0.75373054535289, 0.744182776087168, 0.750360310528986, 0.729454007339541, 
0.689579510122758, 0.72112674182783, 0.657885627799077, 0.701900533545608, 
0.609234874649551, 0.601879472579112, 0.490294075981452, 0.509829319380846, 
0.472809338780224, 0.408395901499169, 0.421004544811214, 0.423042901901428, 
0.438408047449248, 0.399887799175123, 0.438507231574244, 0.440978729860945, 
0.427452056121215, 0.419429561424577, 0.452336733763731, 0.404481012960218, 
0.434546565963827, 0.446080357845563, 0.410747413201042, 0.383562796680424, 
0.371210553112415, 0.34346911715667, 0.334810735560917, 0.332167763120316, 
0.286944801119168, 0.292472860880887, 0.227121939115669, 0.209988381061869, 
0.184553378699683, 0.134753648607438, 0.10541234272905, 0.0736824465640457, 
0.0509363814623246, 0.0446850619000161, 0.0333505481741151, 0.0310597851463593, 
0.023990120152714, 0.0141279042905305, 0.00948655889980178, 0.00961761668483217, 
0.013647879592119)
pop.M<-c(0.573498351502067, 0.559292850391096, 0.587177401716395, 0.589887770190093, 
0.588632714462086, 0.582799990453668, 0.572319898687705, 0.639253707765031, 
0.615297152575117, 0.62753885496394, 0.627469805867318, 0.628316755817131, 
0.614195396078444, 0.625263144405424, 0.62820756554879, 0.642486348714843, 
0.635222563161176, 0.642247362242945, 0.546223088863744, 0.540921786539692, 
0.523715690842238, 0.516831976375647, 0.548392273363241, 0.538983708721224, 
0.539523158138436, 0.530272770738305, 0.569871408826156, 0.593560846001209, 
0.590887010106061, 0.60584831135686, 0.560921833539479, 0.589613005894475, 
0.591717250134999, 0.589201280552838, 0.660506618318706, 0.62325995550515, 
0.710516465510622, 0.750103418376381, 0.781971429033322, 0.763383864636709, 
0.793191548506482, 0.792852871082944, 0.807731860489672, 0.843721081070541, 
0.845288495908646, 0.87871594444754, 0.818215398802191, 0.814267973371801, 
0.796261000366516, 0.755578833361873, 0.76948171414485, 0.781161207873239, 
0.77068819475473, 0.769438354921705, 0.754416212846491, 0.762661772386676, 
0.707131620789663, 0.759594671926447, 0.71205784820271, 0.700131003325457, 
0.687487888906007, 0.62393685492915, 0.566039884964112, 0.464182047253528, 
0.477693083338275, 0.449349375282603, 0.391897602217956, 0.434015766764133, 
0.399268447612815, 0.401161345456143, 0.402684670450875, 0.389145826602956, 
0.354706513557138, 0.37697109209312, 0.327112697365322, 0.332857584899843, 
0.321479371558876, 0.32529563106868, 0.299304941717048, 0.252199941189773, 
0.242782004172793, 0.209119927808453, 0.191656734030685, 0.167093640871562, 
0.134584318985325, 0.121112109833509, 0.0849468834353985, 0.0750695671482072, 
0.0644671239198456, 0.0470356270239876, 0.029820556702351, 0.0242847650917391, 
0.0126581954114024, 0.0104516881602133, 0.00627681510522309, 
0.00898725190805402, 0.00384592156266383, 0.00409269066014978, 
0.00233983745005404, 0.00125801049286461, 0.00188512556114115)
```

Here's the code:

```
    agelabels<-c("0","","","","","5","","","","","10","","","","","15","","","","","20",
         "","","","","25","","","","","30","","","","","35","","","","","40",
         "","","","","45","","","","","50","","","","","55","","","","","60",
         "","","","","65","","","","","70","","","","","75","","","","","80",
         "","","","","85","","","","","90","","","","","95","","","","","100")



pyramide <- function(data,laxis,raxis) {
  par(cex=0.8)
  a<-as.character(x$A); m<-x$m; f<-x$f
  ff<- -m
  ll<- -laxis
  op<-par(mfrow=c(1,2),omi=c(0,0,0,0),ps=18,xaxt="s",cex=0.8)

  par(mar=c(4,2,3,1.5))

  barplot(ff,
          horiz=T,main="Hommes",
          space=0,
          col="grey",
          xlim=c(min(ll),0),
          axes=F,
          axisnames=F,
          cex.axis =0.7,
          xaxt="n")

  axis(1,
       at=ll,
       labels=formatC(laxis,format="d"),
       cex.axis =0.7)

  par(mar=c(4,2,3,2), xaxt="s")

  barplot(f,
          horiz=T,
          main="Femmes",
          space=0,col="grey",
          xlim=c(0,max(raxis)),
          axes=T,axisnames=T,
          cex.axis =0.7)

  axis(2,
       at=c(1:NROW(a))-0.5,
       labels=formatC(a,format="s"),
       pos=-2,
       las=1,tcl=0,
       lty=0,
       cex.axis =0.9)
  par(op)
}

ages <- agelabels
l <-c(seq(1,0,by=-0.2))
r <-c(seq(0,1,by=0.2))
x <- data.frame(A<-ages, m<-pop.M, f<-pop.F)

pyramide(x,l,r)
```

Comment: In `axis(1, ...` change the format to `"fg"` and in `axis(2, ...` use `line=.5` instead of `pos=-2`. Anyway, your function uses objects from the global environment instead of the data provided!

Comment: Thanks @shadow, I now have the following result : <http://tinypic.com/r/mu8sj8/5> Is there a way to add a ".0" to the 1 and the 0 on the left axis (or take them off the right axis) - just to have both axis exactly the same ?

Comment: To get one digit, use `format(..., digits=1)`

Comment: There is a simple solution using `ggplot2` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897329/population-pyramid-plot-with-ggplot2-and-dplyr-instead-of-plyr).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simplification of your code that should do the trick (and fixes some references to global objects):

```
pyramide <- function(data,laxis,raxis) {
  a <- as.character(data$A)
  m<-data$m
  f<-data$f
  ff<- -m

  par(mai=c(1,1,1,.2))
  layout(matrix(1:2,nrow=1))
  barplot(ff,
          horiz=T,main="Hommes",
          space=0,
          col="grey",
          xlim=c(-1,0),
          axes=F,
          axisnames=F,
          cex.axis =0.7,
          xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
  axis(1,
       at=-laxis,
       labels=sprintf("%1.1f",laxis),
       cex.axis =0.7)

  par(mai=c(1,.3,1,1))
  barplot(f,
          horiz=T,
          main="Femmes",
          space=0,col="grey",
          xlim=c(0,1),
          axes=F,axisnames=F,
          cex.axis =0.7)
  axis(1,
       at=laxis,
       labels=sprintf("%1.1f",laxis),
       cex.axis =0.7)
  axis(2,
       at=as.numeric(a),
       labels=a,
       las=1,tcl=0,
       lty=0,
       cex.axis =0.5)
}

ages <- agelabels
l <-seq(1,0,by=-0.2)
r <-seq(0,1,by=0.2)
x <- data.frame(A=ages, m=pop.M, f=pop.F)

pyramide(x,l,r)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice.  I guess that the "Hommes" x-axis should also run from 0.0 to 1.0 (right to left), instead of from -0.0 to -1.0.  So, l=-1*seq(1,0,by=-0.2)  ?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. Would it be possible to add a line to the barplot to represent a second data series? Something using lines() - I've tried calling the 1st barplot a1 and doing lines(x=a1, y=ff) but nothing is plotted.

Comment: @user2568648 In this code I use `layout` which basically draws the left plot then starts over and draws the right plot. If you want to add anything to the left plot, you should add it to the function before the right-hand `barplot` is called. Anything after the function finishes drawing will get added to the right-hand plot only.