# age pyramid in R (using group data)

Tags: r, plot, graph, charts, ggplot2

I would like to plot a age pyramid in R, similar to [Population pyramid plot with ggplot2 and dplyr (instead of plyr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897329/population-pyramid-plot-with-ggplot2-and-dplyr-instead-of-plyr).

The problem is that my data is already aggregated by subgroups. So I don't want to count the number of occurence of age 65, but the sum of all numbers that are of age 65.

eg:

```
df = structure(list(number = c(26778, 28388, 23491, 18602, 15787, 
24536), gender = c("F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M"), age = c(65, 
65, 65, 65, 74, 58)), .Names = c("number", "gender", "age"), row.names = c(142L, 
234L, 243L, 252L, 298L, 356L), class = "data.frame")
```

How should I change this code:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = age, fill = gender)) + 
  geom_bar(data = subset(df, gender == "M")) + 
  geom_bar(data = subset(df, gender == "F"), 
           mapping = aes(y = - ..count.. ),
           position = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs) +
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could summarize the data beforehand and then pass it onto ggplot like below:

```
df1 <- df %>% group_by(gender,age) %>% summarise(s_age = sum(age))

ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = age,y=s_age, fill = gender)) + 
  geom_bar(data = filter(df1, gender == "F"), stat = "identity" ) + 
  geom_bar(data = filter(df1, gender == "M"), stat="identity", aes(y=-s_age) ) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]