# population pyramid for different value in a data frame

Tags: r

I want to create population pyramid. in `mydata`, I have two groups of data for two countries `italy` and `india` . what I need is creating population pyramid for both country.

```
df<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "male", 
population =c(180,160,130,140,150,160,170,90,85,80,75,70,65,60,40), country = "italy")
                
df1<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "female", 
population =c(160,150,120,130,140,150,160,80,75,70,65,60,55,50,30),country  = "italy")

df2<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "male", 
 population =c(185,165,135,148,159,166,177,99,89,88,74,73,68,63,43), country = "india")

df3<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "female", 
 population =c(150,143,117,126,134,144,157,77,71,67,56,51,49,40,24), country = "india")
mydata<- rbind(df,df1,df2,df3)
```

Comment: Maybe you should start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680075/simpler-population-pyramid-in-ggplot2 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897329/population-pyramid-plot-with-ggplot2-and-dplyr-instead-of-plyr

Comment: I saw that post but did not help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=age, y = ifelse(gender == "male", - population, population), fill=gender)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~country) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: @ thanks stefan. can I animate this two pyramids?

Comment: In principle this is possible using `gganimate`. See e.g. https://towardsdatascience.com/population-pyramid-animation-cfa7c1a79a63